# How to add a response header in ApolloServer?

Tags: express, graphql, apollo-server

I am using graphql ApolloServer and using following for Apolloserver

```
server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' });
```

And I need to pass the error returned from the resolvers in the response header.

I read through the docs but looks like we cannot add another middleware after the above-mentioned middleware.

I also tried adding a `formatResponse`  while initializing the server but the object here is not the actual http response where i can change the error header.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  validationRules: [depthLimit(7)],
  playground: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  formatError: err => {
    // Don't give the specific errors to the client.
    if (err.message.startsWith('Database Error: ') || err.message.startsWith('connect')) {
      return new Error('Internal server error');
    }

    // Otherwise return the original error. The error can also
    // be manipulated in other ways, so long as it's returned.
    return err;
  },
  formatResponse: (res:any,options:any) => {

   // can't set headers here as it is not the http response object.


    return res;
  }
});
```

Is there any option available to do this?

Answer (score 7):

```
new ApolloServer({
  context: ({res}) => {
    res.header('key', 'value')
  }
})
```

reference: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I still dont understand this actually, how can i set the 'value' from a mutation?

Answer (score 6):

```
const buildContext = async ({ res, req }) =>
  // Attach additional properties to context if needed
  ({
    user: req.user,
    res,
    req
  });
```

Works with the 'apollo-server-express' integration package.

```
import { ApolloServer } = 'apollo-server-express';
...
const server = new ApolloServer({
  // schema, etc...
  context: ({ res, req }) => buildContext({ res, req }),
  formatResponse: (response, query ) => {
    const { context } = query;
    const { res, req: request } = context; // http response and request
    // now you can set http response headers
   // res.set(...)


    const { data } = response;  // graphql response's data
    const { headers = {} } = request; // http request headers
    return response; // graphql response
  },
});
```

Comment: why request is undefined

Comment: I've update the answer specifying that it is also needed to manually add the request to the context on the apollo server context handler.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [Rico's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57859724/8087608), `formatResponse` has been removed in  [Apollo-server V4](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration#formatresponse-hook).

So if you are using **Apollo-server V4**, you can use

```
new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  plugins: [
    {
      async requestDidStart() {
        return {
          async willSendResponse(requestContext) {
            const { response } = requestContext;
            response.http.headers.set('key', 'value');
          },
        };
      },
    },
  ],
});
```